# Firebase Cloud Functions Node.js: Sometimes Firestore returns document very slowly

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

there

I found interesting issue with Firebase Firestore database doc(DOC_ID).get() function.
Usually it works fine and very fast but in rare case the next code works near 2.5 - 3 seconds in my cloud function:

```
console.log("StreamID", streamId)

const stream = await admin.firestore()
               .collection(COLLECTION_PRODUCT_STREAMS)
               .doc(streamId).get();

console.log("Product stream obj", stream.id)
```

Here is the log from Google Cloud Function
[image]

Comment: Can you share the **entire** code of your Cloud Function?

Comment: hi, I can but other part of this function in logs shows normal result https://gist.github.com/alexkorolchuk/a18b3ea3dc11a3d734a7c5c0e70978b3

Comment: We are using Firesore onWrite listener method over the Firebase function and experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty typical of Firebase Functions. They are very clear in their documentation that servers are spun up on function call, and put to sleep after, to reduce cost. The trade-off is latency during spin up time.

There are some performance considerations in their [tips & tricks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips) section which may help resolve some issues.

Also note that data is stored in cache so depending on how frequently you call the function, or if you query data which has never been fetched, your response time may vary.

Finally, you should implement some error handling and ensure that your function terminates promptly to prevent it from continuing to run after serving the intended purpose.

Comment: You are right but I guess we are speaking about different things. I know and can see that cold start of the function sometimes spend 2-3 secs and this is ok, but there is a firestore request and it works very long time after cold start but sometimes after hot start too. So firestore cannot work so long time to return doc by id because this is useless to have such time delay for this operation. Plus it works quickly from other clients (mobile for example) and there are no big complex request to do this operation so I think there is another problem. But thank for your answer